# Sort a list of objects by size of collection in member field, using streams in Java

Tags: java

I create a record User:

```java
public record User(String name, int age, List<String> skills, boolean isActive) {
}
```

and a list of users:

```java
    private static List<User> prepareData() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        users.add(new User("Kamil", 35, List.of("Java", "Python", "JavaScript"), true));
        users.add(new User("Mariusz", 36, List.of("Java", "C++", "C#"), true));
        users.add(new User("Dominik", 30, List.of("Java", "Dart", "Python"), false));
        users.add(new User("Paulina", 36, List.of("PHP", "SQL", "Python"), false));
        users.add(new User("Rafał", 40, List.of("C#", "Dart"), true));
        users.add(new User("Agnieszka", 29, List.of("Java", "Scala", "Kotlin", "Haskell", "Clojure"), false));
        users.add(new User("Weronika", 43, List.of("Python", "C#", "VBA"), true));

        return users;
    }
```

Now I need to find a user who knows the most technologies (using stream!) and display his name and a list of technologies. I've been trying to get my head around how I can sort a list in a stream. I've tried with Comparator method but it throws an error:

```java
        users.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::skills))
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Well, a `List<String>` is not `Comparable`. You want to sort by number of known technologies, meaning you likely want to sort by the length of the skills list. So, create a comparator that compares the list's length, not the list itself.

Comment: What is your actual requirement?  To `a)` sort the list and then `b)` find the user with the maximum skills, or to just do `(b)`?

Comment: What I want to achieve is b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... Now I need to find a user who knows the most technologies (using stream!) and display his name and a list of technologies. ..."*

There is the possibility that more than one *User*, will have the same amount of skills.
For this, utilize a *[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html)* *[Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html)*; where the last entry will be a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)* of *User* objects, with the most skills.

```java
users = users.stream()
             .collect(
                 Collectors.groupingBy(
                     x -> x.skills().size(),
                     TreeMap::new,
                     Collectors.toList()))
             .lastEntry()
             .getValue();
```

And optimally, extend the *[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)* *class*, to *[encapsulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))* the *add* method.

```java
class UsersList extends ArrayList<User> {
    boolean add(String name, int age, List<String> skills, boolean isActive) {
        return super.add(new User(name, age, skills, isActive));
    }
}
```

Output

```
User[name=Agnieszka, age=29, skills=[Java, Scala, Kotlin, Haskell, Clojure], isActive=false]
```

Although, this approach is fairly un-intuitive.
Typically, *[stream operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)* are used for *[aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_aggregation)*, or *[producing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval)*, data—e.g., *mapping*, *filtering*, etc.—and, not necessarily for calculating values.
While the functionality is abstracted, it's not what is plausibly, pragmatic, in terms of *design constructs*, and *scalable interfaces*.

With that, I recommend using a basic *for-loop* iteration.

```java
List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
User u;
int i, m = users.get(0).skills().size(), n = users.size(), t;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if ((t = users.get(i).skills().size()) > m) m = t;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if ((u = users.get(i)).skills().size() == m) list.add(u);
```

Or, a *[ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)*.

```java
int m = users.get(0).skills().size(), t;
ListIterator<User> li = users.listIterator(1);
while (li.hasNext())
    if ((t = li.next().skills().size()) > m) m = t;
li = users.listIterator();
while (li.hasNext())
    if (li.next().skills().size() != m) li.remove();
```

Comment: `And optimally, extend the ArrayList class, to encapsulate the add method.` Why?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Stream#max` instead of sorting:

```
User result = users.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(user -> user.skills.size()))
                .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Indeed, `max` will be `O(N)` while sorting will be `O(NlogN)` and significantly slower.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare by the `size` of the `List` of skills to get the result ordered by the number of skills the `User` has. Define a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) like the following.

```java
var res = 
    users
        .stream()
        .sorted(
            Comparator
                .comparingInt(
                    (User u) -> u.skills().size()
                )
                .reversed()
        )
        .toList();
// sorted in descending order of number of skills
System.out.println(res);
```

You could also use [`Stream#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) if you only want the one `User` with the greatest amount of skills.

```java
User res = users.stream().max(
   Comparator.comparingInt(u -> u.skills().size())).orElse(null);
```